# Pandas Dataframe automatically shorten strings?

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

I was trying to convert dictionary to pandas dataframe. I have pretty long string in the original dictionary but when I convert into dataframe, I see these strings get shortened. Do anyone know how to store whole string in the dataframe?

Here is some code:

To convert into Dataframe

```
test = pd.DataFrame(res['Items'][-1]['Item'])
```

Whole string code from dictionary

```
res['Items'][-1]['Item']['catchcopy']
```

Output:

```
'クリスタルガイザー / クリスタルガイザー(Crystal Geyser) / ミネラルウォーター 500ml 48本 水 ケース☆送料無料☆'
```

Shortened string code from dataframe

```
test.catchcopy
```

Output:

```
0    クリスタルガイザー / クリスタルガイザー(Crystal Geyser) / ミネラルウォ...
Name: catchcopy, dtype: object
```

Comment: Consider to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: please provide sample of dict, panda and your code used to convert it

Comment: Thanks, I added some code in the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You seem to be confusing the *content* of the pandas cell with its *display*. If you want to change the latter, try using [`display.max_colwidth`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html), like so:

```
pd.set_option('max_colwidth',40)
```

---

Also, if your DataFrame is `df` and the column name is `'c'`, you can access the contents of a cell using:

```
df['c'].values[1]
```

(for the second cell, e.g.). If you `print` this, for example, you should see your Python interpreter's rendition of the string.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks Ami. If you want to temporarily display entire string of a certain cell, how would you do it? Or is it possible?

Comment: @user3368526 See update.

Comment: Great, worked :D Thank you!

Comment: You're very welcome.